# polymer 1.0 data binding not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, polymer

I'm trying to bind some data in a custom element but to no avail. I have a system-menu.html that has my custom element:

**system-menu.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-menu-behavior/iron-menubar-behavior.html">

<dom-module id="system-menu">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
            <li>{{item.name}}</li>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
(function() {
  Polymer({
        is: 'system-menu',
        behaviors: [
          Polymer.IronMenubarBehavior
        ],

        ready: function() {
            console.log(this.data);

      }
  });
})();
</script>
```

This is how I use it (Note that i've done all imports for the other items)

```
<link rel="import" href="/themes/_components/custom_components/system-menu/system-menu.html">

 <style>

    .list {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 8px 0;
    }

    .list li {
      display: block;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    .list li[disabled] {
      color: #ccc;
    }

  </style>

<system-menu class="list flex horizontal end-justified layout" data="{{data}}"></system-menu>
```

Also, ***{{data}}*** in this file is json encoded data from php. Here it is

> {"login":{"url":"/login","parent_id":"0"},"register":{"url":"/register","parent_id":"0"}}

My question is, how am I supposed to access and use this json data data in my ***system-menu.html*** module?

Currently i'm getting these error:

> [dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for `items`, found
>   {
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getKey' of undefined

Comment: @user241584 is exactly right - your `{{data}}` is an object, not an array. However that's just one of the problems in your code. What exactly are you expecting in the output?

Comment: @zerodevx I simply need an example on its usage in `system-menu.html` , whichever way

Comment: It creates a list item which translates to a menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to transform your json `{{data}}` into an array of objects readable by `<template is='dom-repeat'>`. I assume that you want

> {"login":{"url":"/login","parent_id":"0"},"register":{"url":"/register","parent_id":"0"}}

to become something like

> [ {name: "login", url: "/login", parent_id: "0"}, {name: "register", url: "/register", parent_id: "0"} ]

The actual code to do the above should be trivial and beyond the scope of this question.

Second, you need to publish the `data` property in your `<system-menu>` custom element since you are binding the `data` attribute from the parent template.

> `<system-menu class="list flex horizontal end-justified layout" data="{{data}}"></system-menu>`

You can pass in a computed function (to perform the conversion from your json `{{data}}` into the `dom-repeat`-compatible array) into the `items` attribute in the `<template is='dom-repeat'>` tag.

Putting it all together, your `system-menu.html` might look something like that

```
<dom-module id="system-menu">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_transformData(data)}}">
            <li>{{item.name}}</li>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
        is: 'system-menu',
        behaviors: [
          Polymer.IronMenubarBehavior
        ],
        properties: {
          data: Object
        },
        _transformData: function (d) {

          // place transformation code here

          return transformedDataThatIsNowAnArray;
        },
        ready: function() {
          console.log(this.data);
        }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, figured out as much. let me take a look at it then i'll accept your ans. Got any fancy idea for the `_transformData` function? looked for examples on how to change my object to array but nada. I really don't feel like changing my data strucure.

Comment: Nothing fancy... I'll just do a `for (var k in data)` to iterate through the json object, then construct the array? There might be better ways to do this - perhaps you can create a new question on that.

Comment: cant i use `handle-as="json"` somewhere to handle the array conversion? will save me a lot of headache.